# The given key was not present in the dictionary. Using Parse Object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

```
public async Task<Items> RetrieveItems(string objectId)
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Item");
        ParseObject p = await query.GetAsync(objectId);
        Items returnEvent = new Items()
       {
           ItemName = p.Get<string>("ItemName"),
           ItemPrice = p.Get<string>("ItemPrice"),
           ItemDescription = p.Get<string>("ItemDescription"),
           Id = p.ObjectId,
       };
        return returnEvent;
    }
```

I dont Know where is Error :(

```
   public async Task<List<Items>> GetItems()
    {
        List<Items> iii = new List<Items>();
        try
        {
            var query = (from Item in ParseObject.GetQuery("Item")
                         orderby Item.CreatedAt
                         select Item);
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> items = await query.FindAsync();
            foreach (var ii in items)
            {
                Items e = await this.RetrieveItems(ii.Get<string>("Item"));

                iii.Add(e);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error is "+ ex.Message);

        }
        return iii;
    }
```

Out Put is The given key was not present in the dictionary. !!

just I want to return Data from Parse Object using Linq Query  To Long list Selector Or List Box

Comment: You're not alone. I don't know where the error is either without you pointing out the line of code that throws an exception or doesn't behave like you think it should.

Comment: The Error is in the second Part but I don't Know Where Exactly
I have tried many times

Comment: run your apps in debug mode, put breakpoint at the beginning of both method, then step line by line to find out which line exactly throwing the exception. Remove/remark try-catch could also help to spot source of exception

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn more on how to debug. Isolate the problem to single line of code, then your job to find out why it is throwing exception and how to fix it will be far easier.

First thing I will do is, as mentioned in comment, put breakpoint at the beginning of both method, run the project in debug mode, then step line by line (press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd>) to find out which line exactly throwing the exception.

From current information, I can only guess that possible problem is, the `ParseObject` doesn't contain property that you're trying to get. Check column names in the parse.com data browser, and see if it match column name that your code trying to access.

If you manage to debug the code and find that it is throwing exception at line that do something like :

```
ParseObjectVariable.Get<string>("columnName");
```

then it could indicate that my guess was right.